# How to match Button height with another button when they are on different linearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have two different LinearLayout(vertical). 1st LinearLayout has 3 buttons named btnX, btnY, btnZ. 2nd LinearLayout has 2 buttons named btnA, btnB. btnB top alignment should follow btnY. If I add a new button btnX(suppose), btnB height will be increased as given picture. You can get a clear idea from it.

[image]

Comment: show your layout code, what you have tried so far

Comment: I'd put them all in a relative layout without the linear layouts so I can add that as a rule, and at the same time reduce my layout depth (and thus overdraw) by one.

Comment: If LinearLayout is not doing what you want it to, consider using a different layout.  RelativeLayout may be just what you need.

Comment: @DaleWilson I want the idea. I couldn't use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout in my project.

Comment: @joyoares Have you tried to make that *layout* ?

Comment: @GabeSechan I couldn't use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout in my project

Comment: @joyoares There's no reason you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You could use layout weight.
In your LinearLayouts, add 
`android:weightSum=3`

Then, assign this to each layout:
`android:layout_weight=1`

That way, any button will take up 1/3 of the height, regardless of how many layouts you have. If you want a button to take 2/3 of the height, set layout_weight to 2.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution is to implement a relative layout... but you could try putting your button B inside another independent linearlayout and put them inside a relativelayout

Answer (score 0):

Explain more about it, but i hope it helps. change width and height as you like, height of button B is ((Height of button A)*2)+margin top of buttons

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnZ"
    android:layout_width="216dp"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Button Z"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnY"
    android:layout_width="216dp"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Button Y"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnZ"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnX"
    android:layout_width="216dp"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Button X"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnY"/>
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnA"
    android:layout_width="216dp"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Button A"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnB"
    android:layout_width="216dp"
    android:layout_height="196dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Button B"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnA"/>
```